# Why is the del operator in python so slow, and are there quicker alternatives?

Tags: python, optimization, audio, del

I'm writing some driver code for an audio application. I have a buffer of audio samples, stored as ints, which I'm converting to bytes just before I send them off.

If I play a short wav file, for example, the buffer is filled to a size of about 600000 elements.

What I'm doing is converting the samples, then deleting the converted samples from the buffer, like so:

```py
def start_playback_thread(self):
    # self.alsa_buffer is a Queue type object
    i = 0
    begin_time = time.time()
    while True:
        self.buffer_mutex.acquire()
        if len(self.buffer) - offset == 0:
            self.buffer_mutex.release()
            self.sleep_time(begin_time)
            continue
 
        # Convert samples to bytes
        size = min(self.period_size, self.buffer_size)
        self.alsa_buffer.put(struct.pack(
                "<{}h".format(size),
                *[self.correct_val(x) for x in self.buffer[:size]]
            )
        )

        if self.buffer_size - offset < self.period_size:
            self.alsa_buffer.put(b"\x00" * (self.buffer_size - self.period_size))

        # Delete used samples from buffer
        del self.buffer[:size]      # < here
        self.buffer_size -= size

        self.buffer_mutex.release()
        i += 1
        if i > 10000:
            break
    logger.debug("Took {:.6f} vs target {:.6f}".format((time.time() - begin_time) / i, self.period_length_time))
```

The usage of `i` and `begin_time` is for timing this only.

Now, I am using a sample rate of 44100Hz and a period size of 32 frames. This means, I have to send one period every 0.000726s *at a maximum*.

The above code takes 0.000773s per period. This is too long. However, I removed the `del` operation and replaced it with a simple 'offset' so that nothing is deleted, and suddenly the time shot down to only 0.000079s - one *order of magnitude* quicker.

`del` was slowing everything down. But why?

And, since I'm not a massive fan of using an 'offset', what alternatives are there that might be quicker?

Comment: have you tried `self.buffer = self.buffer[size:]` ? or is this the 'offset' you mean?

Comment: the 'offset' was just storing the last index that I read from and reading from that point on the next loop. That way `self.buffer` was never modified apart from the initial write into it and it was very quick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to copy the needed part of the original list?

`self.buffer = self.buffer[size:]`

Using del can be slower as all objects will be destructed using the `__del__` function defined in you class. That can be slow if the `__del__` function slow itself (but you may not notice that by a given deletion).

Using list slicing is a way faster method as it does not replicate the objects.

The other technique you could use is a sliding windows iterator, I'm not sure if it exists in Python builtins.

Also, for a specific sized FIFO array, you can use `deque` from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque), or you can check if there's anything useful in collections to your specific problem.

Comment: Yes, I have. This is actually _slower_, taking 0.011391s per period.